# Please could you explain this code, line 8 in particular ; the one with the loop in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, generator

An explanation would mightily help. In particular the line with the loop

```
import string
from random import *

letters = string.ascii_letters 
digits = string.digits 
symbols = string.punctuation
chars = letters + digits + symbols

min_length = 8
max_length = 16
password = "".join(choice(chars) for x in range(randint(min_length, max_length)))
print(password)
```

Comment: Shortly , generate a minimum 8 and maximum 16 length string that contains letters, digits and symbols.

Comment: Line 8 is an empty line :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an equivalent to the line with the `for`. Hope this helps.

```
# We will temporally store the password character in this list 
password_chars = []

# Choose a random length for the password
password_length = randint(min_length, max_length)

# Choose `password_length` random chars for the password
for x in range(password_length):
    # Randomly choose a character from the valid password characters
    random_valid_character = choice(chars)
    # Add the random valid character to the password characters list
    password_chars.append(random_valid_character)

# Join the password character list to form a string
password = ''.join(password_chars)
```

The code you provided uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to write the same loop in a shorter way, sacrificing readability for shortness (one could argue).

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
from random import *

#Strings of ascii letters, digits, and punctuation
letters = string.ascii_letters 
digits = string.digits 
symbols = string.punctuation
#A string combining letters, digits and symbols
chars = letters + digits + symbols

min_length = 8
max_length = 16

#In the range of a random integer between min_length and max_length...
#Choose a random character from the string chars...
#And join the list containing those random characters into one string
password = "".join(choice(chars) for x in range(randint(min_length, max_length)))
print(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

**LINE BY LINE**

`import string`: Imports the string module

`from random import *`: Imports everything from the random module

`letters = string.ascii_letters`: Stores in a list all ascii letters

`digits = string.digits`: Stores in a list all digist (0-9)

`symbols = string.punctuation`: Stores in a list all punctuation marks

`chars = letters + digits + symbols`: Joins the last three lists

`min_length = 8`: Sets the minimum password length to 8

`max_length = 16`: Sets the maximum password length to 16

`password = "".join(choice(chars) for x in range(randint(min_length, max_length)))`: This one is trickier.

- `randint(min_length, max_length)` returns and integer between the minimum and maximum length
- `range()` returns a list like [0,1,2... x-1] where x is the length of the password from the previous part
- `for x in range` cycles through each item in the previous list of integers [0,1,2... x-1], so, in short, one cycle per character in the password
- `choice(chars)` chooses a character randomly from the list chars
- `"".join()`. Not ethat, by this point, we have a list of characters chosen randomly, with a length between 8 and 16. Join basically puts all the characters together in a string, sepparated by "" (empty string, so it puts them together)

Answer (score 0):

The entire code is actually a basic code for creating passwords.
To create a password , we first need the elements of it viz digits , alphabets , characters.

Once we have the units ready , the code defines the maximum and the minimum length of the password

Finally , in the for loop part , the code generates a list of random length between the max_length and min_length.

So, each time you run , a new password of different length gets created.